# php - show sql value with line break on retrieve

Tags: php, sql, line-breaks

i'm using the following code to show clickable pictures, but underneath the picture it shows a description for the picture, in this part:

```
<br>".$row['optie'];"
```

but some lines in the table are too long to display the picture and description correctly next to each other. 
So how can i show these descriptions and add a line break?

```
<?php   
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabel";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $aantal = 0;

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";

    while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
    {
        $src = $row['afbeelding'];

        echo '<div class="Image">';
        echo "<td align='center'><h2><a href='pagina3.php?lang=" . $_SESSION['lang'] . "&naam=" . $naam . "&postcodehuisnummer=" .$postcodehuisnummer ."&fietskeuze=" . $fietskeuze . "&opties=" . $row['optie'] . "&optieid=" . $row['opties_id'] . "' '><img src=".$src." width='400px'><br>".$row['optie'];"</a><br /><br /> ";
        echo '</div>';
        $aantal++;
        if ($aantal==3) {echo "<tr>"; $aantal=0;} 
    }
    echo "</tr></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: As opposed to just concatenating "\n" or <br>?

Comment: anything that works :) can you show how my url would have too look like for that?

Comment: Well how does your URL look now? I don't see an example :).

Comment: this line: echo "<td align='center'><h2><a href='pagina3.php?lang=" . $_SESSION['lang'] . "&naam=" . $naam . "&postcodehuisnummer=" .$postcodehuisnummer ."&fietskeuze=" . $fietskeuze . "&opties=" . $row['optie'] . "&optieid=" . $row['opties_id'] . "' '><img src=".$src." width='400px'><br>".$row['optie'];"</a><br /><br /> ";

Comment: your tip about concat worked. i found an example and inserted this to achieve what i wanted: $row['optie'] = str_replace('\r', '<br>', $row['optie']);   Thank you!

Comment: I'll post an answer so people don't keep seeing this. Please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply concatenate your value onto the end of your URL.

```
$row['optie'] = str_replace('\r', '<br>', $row['optie']);
```